# Unable to read data from CSV with 80K records

Tags: php, csv, large-files, fgetcsv

I am trying to read CSV with over 80K records. Unfortunately, I am not able to achieve it. Can some one please help me?
My CSV is around 100MB and I have increased the memory_limit to 128M.

I have increased the memory_limit to 128M.
I tried using below code:

```
 $handle = fopen('products.csv');
  if ($handle !== FALSE) {
      $str ='';
      echo "IN";
      while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
        $str .= json_encode($data); // add each json string to a string variable, save later
        $array[]=$data;
      }
  }

  fclose($handle);
  $finalJsonString = json_encode($array);
  print_r($finalJsonString);
```

`Output: null`

Can someone please help me if you have an idea about it?

Thanks

Comment: for starters, you use `fgetcsv($handle)`, but your handle variable is `$h`

Comment: @jibsteroos:Thanks for your response. Sorry, I forgot to update the code. I have updated the code. the output is same.

Comment: what exactly gives you `Output: null`? And what purpose does `$str` serve?

Comment: Try getting rid of the `$str` variable that keeps getting bigger with each line that is read. If your input file is 100MB that string will end up being that big and then some.

Comment: You're going to be holding a lot more than 100MB here. First, you are building `$str` - which is data + JSON syntax. You are building `$array` which is just data. You are building `$finalJsonString` which is data + JSON syntax, and finally you are echoing `$finalJsonString`, which will be putting data + JSON syntax into the system output buffer. That's over 400MB right there.

Answer (score 0):

To solve memory usage problems with large files, you could use a generator.

A generator allows you to use a foreach to iterate over a set of data without needing to build an array in memory, which may cause you to exceed a memory limit, or require a considerable amount of processing time to generate (source: [php.net generators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php)).

This should help you on your way:

```
// the generator
function readCsv($csv)
{
    $handle = fopen($csv, "r");
    if ($handle) {
        while (!feof($handle)) {
            yield fgetcsv($handle);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
}

// initialize variables
$data = [];
$line = null;
$csv = "test.csv"; // change this to the csv-file you want to read
/* 
 * in the foreach do some logic
 * with the yielded csv content
 */
foreach(readCsv($csv) as $line) {
    // show for debug
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($line);
    echo '</pre>';
}

// show memory usage
echo "memory peak usage (Kb): " . memory_get_peak_usage()/1024;
```

Comment: You should probably include a `flush();` call in your foreach to stop the system output buffer getting too big.

Comment: Yeah, good suggestion, I just used a `var_dump()` for debugging purposes on a small test file. I would advise the OP to not try to echo 100MB of csv content...